# Facebook Like Button Dislikes My Code

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-like

I've been trying to implement a Facebook Like button on my blog like this:

```
$("#fblike").append(" <iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=217624258276389&amp;" + window.location.href + "&amp;send=false&amp;layout=box_count&amp;width=50&amp;show_faces=false&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;font&amp;height=60' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:50px; height:60px;' allowTransparency='true'></iframe>");
```

And adding this to the `<head>` of my HTML source file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
```

The problem is that when I try to test the Like button it shows 1 instead of 0 and a second later goes back to 0. Nothing changed at my Facebook profile neither. What's wrong and how to correct this?

*PS: I'm running this on a localhost server, in my case `http://nathan-camposs-macbook-pro.local/~Nathan`*

Answer (score 1):

I think the events go something like:

1. You click the button.
2. Javascript sends the like request to FB.
3. Facebook tries to access your page ("localhost").
4. It can't access it so the request is denied.

**UPDATE:-**

I noticed that your src attribute starts: `'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=217624258276389&amp;" + window.location.href + "&amp;`

i think it should be: `'http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?app_id=217624258276389&amp;href=" + window.location.href + "&amp;`

notice the **`href=`**

Comment: Just tested on my Rackspace server and I'm having the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I've had problems testing the like on sites using temp urls - Facebook doesn't like it when the associated app_id value is not related to the url of the page you're trying to like.  But I could be wrong.  If you temporarily expand the width to something beyond 50 (like 300-350), there should be an "error" link that pops up that will give you some more valuable information...

Answer (score 0):

If you use fbml then you will not need the application ID. Using fbml you can configure several things. I think you already have a look at-

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

You can try the following code

```
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
</head>
```

Then in the body

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:like href="http://yoururl" send="true" width="450" show_faces="true" font="">
</fb:like>
```